# Is it possible to simulate oracle machines on 1-dimensional cellular automata?

Tags: automata, simulation, oracle-machines, cellular-automata

My instinctual response is that it is possible, but I can't see how to simulate the oracle tape on a 1-d CA.

If not, are they able to be simulated on n-dimensional CA? My thought is that the oracle tape could be simulated on another row in, say, a 2+1-dimensional cellular automaton.

Comment: are you limited in the kernel size and/or number of states?

Comment: Do I interpret kernel size as the number of non-quiescent initial cells here? Also, can you explain why the number of states matters here?

Comment: I think I can answer your question once my confusions are clarified.

Comment: kernel size is how far each cell looks to decide it's next state.

Comment: ah, I see. I think finite fixed kernel size implies inability to simulate an oracle machine, no? and I think we require at least 9 symbols, representing 0, 1, left, right, tape head, oracle tape head, ask, response, halt